# How to split name to first and last name and use in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with Node, Angular & Mongo. And was able to successfully save and retrieve a user from the db. I have in my user model the following -> name: String. This is basically where the user inputs his first and last name.

Now i want to retrieve the name from the database and split the first and lastname up to retrieve the first letter of the first name and last name to create the initials of the user.

My question is how to do this basically:

Part of my app.js code for retrieving the user is the following (in this function I would write the split javascript code):

```
//Retrieving the users
        $scope.getUsers = function() {
            $http.get('/api/users').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.userInfo = data;

                    //console.log("Retrieved users from the server", data);
                    //$scope.linkTaskToUser(data);
                    //console.log(data);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Error in retrieving users from server");
                });


            var FirstLastName = $scope.userInfo.data.name;
            console.log('---->>>>>' , FirstLastName);



        }
        $scope.getUsers();
```

I tried something like this :

```
var FirstLastName = $scope.userInfo.data.name;
console.log('---->>>>>' , FirstLastName);
```

But of course this is not right (throws up an error)....

Comment: How would that throw an error

Comment: Also the only way to split names, will be to insert them correctly, not fully in the database. You cannot guarantee that it is possible to split the names by code. f/e in the Netherlands your last name can be van den moll, and in lots of country you have multiple first names and middle names.

Split them in the database otherwise you'll always run into problems with some localisation.

Comment: @MathijsSegers: the error i get is the following -> http://gyazo.com/f0af3374f0cba7be522c9cde7459f6e5

Comment: @MathijsSegers: the localistion issue is not that big of a problem for my project ..

Comment: Could you check what information userInfo contains? There might be no data node in the object. Just do a console.log ($scope...userInfo). that might clear things up. You're probably accessing the wrong node or getting faulty data.

Comment: @MathijsSegers: i am getting data back -> http://gyazo.com/1563e81cc84b55e626bfe14942e8b6bf

Comment: It seems like there is no data node there. You probably want to loop over the items using ng-repeat and call a function that separates the names, try to display them like this first.

In your example you could probably access the first one using $scope.userInfo[0].name 

you could either iterate over them getting the count of userInfo, or do it in the view and call a controller function with the content. :-)

Comment: @MathijsSegers: yeah nevermind I found the issue. thanks anyway for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First all,put your below code inside success callback:

var FirstLastName = $scope.userInfo.data.name;
            console.log('---->>>>>' , FirstLastName);

Now try to console just data.name. If this one is giving you data then try to console.log($scope.userInfo.name);

Hope this might help you !!
Cheers !!!

Comment: Can you please print your response here ?

Inside success call back write :
console.log(data);

Then let me know the output.

Comment: basically I had to loop first through my users and then i could access the name of my user and then i wrote a function to split the name up to create the initials (I figured it already out so thanks anyway)

Answer (score 1):

get() is asynchron - you have to manage data in the success-function:

```
//Retrieving the users
    $scope.getUsers = function() {
        $http.get('/api/users').success(function(data) {
                $scope.userInfo = data;
                var FirstLastName = $scope.userInfo.data.name;
                console.log('---->>>>>' , FirstLastName);

                //console.log("Retrieved users from the server", data);
                //$scope.linkTaskToUser(data);
                //console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Error in retrieving users from server");
            });

    }
    $scope.getUsers();
```

Comment: did as you suggested but getting an error -> http://gyazo.com/95336ab8ef3a0310b32fc539179954e5

Comment: Please look in success-function what is in data.
Can you debug?
Is data undefined?

Comment: I already solved the issues yesterday. but thanks anyway for your input